# str=str.split('=') AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, xpath, split

I have to pass split the data from xpath into two fields

```
str = response.xpath('.//td//div[@class="cit_maoin"]()')
str=split('=')

print('published)
```

Comment: Can you please show how str looks like after line 1? The reason of this error may come if list is multidimentional or empty.

Comment: add ```print(str)``` as the second line and show what it prints. It isn't a string, but list

Comment: @abi so, remove debug print and line2 after that, ```str=str.split('=')``` just unneeded

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `line 3`

```
str=str[0].split('at')
```

Your list has only one item, so index will be 0, not one. Index starts from 0 in list.
Hope it helped!

Comment: looking on caption i think error in the second line, not third

Comment: in Line 1, str = 'published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM'

Comment: @abi delimits it with '=',  str becomes a list. When i ran his code, he had index 1 with a list containing only one item. When index is substituted to correct value i'e' 0, it produces desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a keyword in Python. 
Let `my_str = 'published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM'`

```
my_str = my_str.split('=')[1]

date_str = my_str.split('at')[0]
time_str = my_str.split('at')[1]

print(date_str) #6/11/2019
print(time_str) #8:02 AM
```

For a list of inputs, use a for loop.

Comment: @abi Use print('published date = ', my_str[0], '\npublished time = ', my_str[1])

Comment: @abi my_str should be a string. Use str(my_str).split('=')[1]

Comment: @abi Your my_str is actually a List. Use spilt() on a String element inside that list or convert it to a String. Improve your answer to give a sense what this is returning: player.xpath('//div[@class="lpadding20"]/text()')

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
str = ['published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM']
published_date, time = str[0][11:].split('at')[0],str[0][11:].split('at')[1]
```

check with this Assuming your mystr as given below

```
my_str = [['\r\n ', '3/28/2019 at 8:52 PM.\r\n This list includes 36 
        eligible players.\r\n ', '\r\n \xa0\r\n '],['\r\n ', '3/28/2019 at 8:52 PM.\r\n This list includes 36 eligible players.\r\n']]



date = []
time = []
for x in my_str:
    index_ = x[1].find('PM')
    string_ =  x[1][0:index_ + 2]
    date.append(string_.split('at')[0])
    time.append(string_.split('at')[1])

#op
print(date)
['3/28/2019 ', '3/28/2019 ']

print(time)

[' 8:52 PM', ' 8:52 PM']
```

Comment: please share  my_str  output

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use str because it's built in keyword in Python. you didn't specify what your desired output should be like but from the Comments I think you ll need some changes like this to your code:

```
    data = ["published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM"]
    results = []
    for s in data:
      t = s.split("=")
      z = t[1].split("at")
      tmp = f'published date = {z[0]} published time = {z[1]} '
      results.append(tmp)

   print(results) # ['published date =  6/11/2019  published time =  8:02 AM ']
```

with this Code you ll get a list of desired outputs. Hope it helps

Comment: should this list contain just one item as a string ?

Comment: just loop through the list and use the code that i posted for every item in that list

Comment: for s in data : 
    t = s.split("=")
    z = t[1].split("at")
    result.append('published date =',z[0],'\npublished time =',z[1]) # then you ll have a list of desired outputs

Comment: is every Element in this list is a string ?